unable to create project from unity
I'm trying to create a project on unity, but I get the error "unable to create project" in the error log "ERROR.LAUNCH_EDITOR.ENOENT" The unity hub is located on disk c, the project is also created on this disk. Editor version 2021.3.22f1
I reinstalled unity several times and tried to change the ways of creating the project.
Sorry for my English.

Alas, Stack Overflow is only for fixing coding problems, this sounds like a software issue.  Better to post on the Unity forms is the TLDR answer.

If you have managed to solve the issue - coding problem or not - adding it as an answer yourself can help other users. You can accept the answer after a few days.

did you try running unity hub as administrator?

Does this answer your question? "Unable to create project" error in Unity hub 3.1.2
